# Смена YMaps markers на Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
include '../include/config.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$act = $_GET['act'];
$sql = "SELECT region.gps AS gps, count(*) AS num FROM inform_objects, region WHERE inform_objects.id_region=region.cod_reg AND id_objects=$id GROUP BY cod_reg";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($act == 'add'){
    $row = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT img_name, offset FROM objects WHERE id=$id"));
    $img = "1_" . $row->img_name;
    $offset = $row->offset;
    echo "function SetMarkers(){
        gCollection_o$id = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
    ";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $point = $row->gps;
        $num = $row->num;
        echo "
        var content = {iconContent: \"<div style='background-color: #fff;'>$num</div>\"},
            styles = {
                iconLayout:\"default#imageWithContent\",
                iconImageHref:\"/templates1/images/$img\",
                iconImageSize:[16,16],
                iconImageOffset:[$offset],
                iconContentOffset: [16,0]
            },
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([$point], content, styles);";
        /* echo "placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([$point]);"; */
        echo "gCollection_o$id.add(placemark);";
    }
    echo "map.geoObjects.add(gCollection_o$id);";

    echo "}";
}
else {
    echo "function DelMarkers(){";
    echo "map.geoObjects.remove(gCollection_o$id);";
    echo "}";
}
?>
```